# Do my other local computers need a static IP when I use port forwarding?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, dhcp

If I change my main computer to static and port forward to get a server hosted, does that mean that I need to change the rest of the laptops and computer on the network to static to get them to connect to the internet?

Comment: No they can be either static or DHCP as you want

Comment: @Nikolay This should be an answer, but ideally with a little more explanation.

Comment: @slhck, thank you. I put this as answer with more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Port forwarding alone does not affect the way of how you assign addresses to devices in your LAN.

When you setup port forwarding you instruct a router to accept packets on a specific port and route them to some port of some device in the LAN.

The device which should receive these packets must have an IP address and it should be known beforehand when you setup port forwarding. So the address should be constant. It does not matter how this address is being assigned. Having a constant address can be achieved in two ways:

1. **Static IP address**. When network interface goes up the device knows what its IP address, subnet mask and default router. So the device sets it appropriately.
2. **Dynamic IP address with static lease.** This means the device itself does not know what its network settings are. It asks a DHCP server for those settings. There is a way to configure DHCP server in the way that it will reserve a particular IP address for a host with particular MAC address. This means even being dynamically assigned, the address will be the same every time. Furthermore, DHCP server can be instructed to give a lease with no expiration. Basically, at this point it will be sort of "static" address. The device will ask for a lease when its network interface goes up and as long as it stays up the device will keep same address and will not try to renew the lease.

Rest of the devices in your LAN can have either static or dynamic addresses. Setting up a port forwarding on the router will not affect communication inside your LAN.

For example, you forward port 80 from `router` to `A`. Address of `A` should be known to `router` and should not be changing over time. `B` and `C` can have static or dynamic addresses regardless of port forwarding.

```
           router
             |
             |
       -------------
       |     |     |
       |     |     |
       A     B     C
```

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not need. The firewall will keep connections for client machines. Only for servers is necessary to have static IP as router should know the exact IP all the time to forward the proper packages. But you can avoid static IP adding DHCP reservation, based on the MAC address of server and the server will receive always the same IP